# sql query distinct with Row_Number

Tags: sql, distinct

I am fighting with the distinct keyword in `sql`.
I just want to display all row numbers of unique (`distinct`) values in a column & so I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNum
FROM table
WHERE fid = 64
```

however the below code giving me the `distinct` values:

```
SELECT distinct id FROM table WHERE fid = 64
```

but when tried it with `Row_Number`.
then it is not working.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNum FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE fid = 64) Base
```

and put the "output" of a query as the "input" of another.

Using CTE:

```
; WITH Base AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE fid = 64
)

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNum FROM Base
```

The two queries should be equivalent.

Technically you could

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS RowNum 
    FROM table
    WHERE fid = 64
```

but if you increase the number of DISTINCT fields, you have to put all these fields in the `PARTITION BY`, so for example

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, description,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, description ORDER BY id) AS RowNum 
    FROM table
    WHERE fid = 64
```

I even hope you comprehend that you are going against standard naming conventions here, `id` should probably be a primary key, so unique by definition, so a `DISTINCT` would be useless on it, unless you coupled the query with some `JOIN`s/`UNION ALL`...

Answer (score 150):

This can be done very simple, you were pretty close already

```
SELECT distinct id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY  id) AS RowNum
FROM table
WHERE fid = 64
```

Comment: This one is way better than the selected answer.

Answer (score 41):

[This article covers an interesting relationship between `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()`](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/) (the `RANK()` function is not treated specifically). When you need a generated `ROW_NUMBER()` on a `SELECT DISTINCT` statement, the [`ROW_NUMBER()` will produce distinct values *before* they are removed by the `DISTINCT` keyword](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/). E.g. this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  v, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v) row_number
FROM t
ORDER BY v, row_number
```

... might produce this result (`DISTINCT` has no effect):

```
+---+------------+
| V | ROW_NUMBER |
+---+------------+
| a |          1 |
| a |          2 |
| a |          3 |
| b |          4 |
| c |          5 |
| c |          6 |
| d |          7 |
| e |          8 |
+---+------------+
```

Whereas this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  v, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY v) row_number
FROM t
ORDER BY v, row_number
```

... produces what you probably want in this case:

```
+---+------------+
| V | ROW_NUMBER |
+---+------------+
| a |          1 |
| b |          2 |
| c |          3 |
| d |          4 |
| e |          5 |
+---+------------+
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` clause of the `DENSE_RANK()` function will need all other columns from the `SELECT DISTINCT` clause to work properly.

#### All three functions in comparison

Using PostgreSQL / Sybase / SQL standard syntax (`WINDOW` clause):

```
SELECT
  v,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (window) row_number,
  RANK()       OVER (window) rank,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (window) dense_rank
FROM t
WINDOW window AS (ORDER BY v)
ORDER BY v
```

... you'll get:

```
+---+------------+------+------------+
| V | ROW_NUMBER | RANK | DENSE_RANK |
+---+------------+------+------------+
| a |          1 |    1 |          1 |
| a |          2 |    1 |          1 |
| a |          3 |    1 |          1 |
| b |          4 |    4 |          2 |
| c |          5 |    5 |          3 |
| c |          6 |    5 |          3 |
| d |          7 |    7 |          4 |
| e |          8 |    8 |          5 |
+---+------------+------+------------+
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `DISTINCT` causes issues as you add fields and it can also mask problems in your select.  Use `GROUP BY` as an alternative like this:

```
SELECT id
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  id) AS RowNum
  FROM table
 where fid = 64
 group by id
```

Then you can add other interesting information from your select like this:

```
,count(*) as thecount
```

or

```
,max(description) as description
```

Comment: Upvoted for using `group by`. But I think `partition by` won't be needed here.

Comment: @P5Coder , Of course you are correct.  I have fixed it.  I have no idea what I was thinking when I put it in there.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
;WITH DistinctVals AS (
        SELECT  distinct id 
        FROM    table 
        where   fid = 64
    )
SELECT  id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  id) AS RowNum
FROM    DistinctVals
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18548)

You could also try

```
SELECT distinct id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY  id) AS RowNum
FROM @mytable
where fid = 64
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18551)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct id
FROM  (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  id) AS RowNum
      FROM table
      WHERE fid = 64) t
```

Or use `RANK()` instead of row number and select records `DISTINCT rank`

```
SELECT id
FROM  (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  id ORDER BY  id) AS RowNum
      FROM table
      WHERE fid = 64) t
WHERE t.RowNum=1
```

This also returns the distinct ids

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
               SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE fid = 64
             )
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  id) AS RowNum
  FROM cte
 WHERE fid = 64
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is too old and my answer might not add much but here are my two cents for making query a little useful:

```
;WITH DistinctRecords AS (
    SELECT  DISTINCT [col1,col2,col3,..] 
    FROM    tableName 
    where   [my condition]
), 
serialize AS (
   SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [colNameAsNeeded] ORDER BY  [colNameNeeded]) AS Sr,*
    FROM    DistinctRecords 
)
SELECT * FROM serialize
```

Usefulness of using two cte's lies in the fact that now you can use serialized record much easily in your query and do `count(*)` etc very easily.

`DistinctRecords` will select all distinct records and `serialize` apply serial numbers to distinct records. after wards you can use final serialized result for your purposes without clutter.

`Partition By` might not be needed in most cases