# Select distinct rows when using row numbers

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Aim: Get distinct values based on fields 'DOCURL' and 'ELEMENT'.

Notes: (editted) The below is to be used on the .aspx page and not in SQL

Issue: If I run as a standalone query I get 14 lines, which is correct;

```
 Select DISTINCT DOCURL, ELEMENT From TblReference Where Property= 'XYZ'
```

My code is pulling up 34 and I've change Row_Number to DENSE_RANK but still not able to get down to 14;

```
Select  * from( Select DISTINCT DOCURL, ELEMENT,
 DENSE_RANK() over (order by id desc) As rn  From TblReference
 Where Property= 'XYZ' ) as t  Where rn = 1
```

*** the rn is in a variable loop to count up to 10 normally.

Reference: [sql query distinct with Row_Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121130/sql-query-distinct-with-row-number) --

```
SELECT distinct id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY  id) AS RowNum
FROM table
WHERE fid = 64
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support window functions!

Comment: The code works spot on bar the removing distinct, in the .NET code where it usually is it starts...  For i = 1 To 10
            sSQL = "Select  * from( Select id, DOCURL, VFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT, row_number() over (order by id desc) As rn  From TblData Where UPRN = '" & Session.Item("pUPRN").ToString & "') as t Where rn = " & i & ""
            dsNames.SelectCommand = sSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySQL doesn't support window functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()` , try doing it with a join :

```
 Select t.DOCURL, t.ELEMENT
 From TblReference t 
 LEFT JOIN TblReference s
  ON(t.docurl = s.docurl and t.element = s.element and s.id < t.id and s.property = 'XYZ')
 Where t.Property= 'XYZ' AND s.id is null
ORDER BY t.OrderColumn
LIMIT 10;
```

I don't know how you use this functions, but your problem was that you didn't use the `PARTITION BY` part :

```
Select  * 
from(Select DISTINCT DOCURL, ELEMENT,
            ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY docurl,element order by id desc) As rn 
     From TblReference
     Where Property= 'XYZ' ) t 
Where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd need to limit this to the first ten and please see amendments above, code will be on the .aspx page so I may have mislead on the initial post (notes added)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know PHP. What is wrong with this query? @indofraiser

Comment: Thanks, both useful. Turned out I has a loop in the wrong place earlier on essentially messing with the 'i' function as well, bit of a red herring!