# SQL Server Comparing 2 tables having Millions of Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

- I have 2 tables in SQL Server: Table 1 and Table 2.
- Table 1 has 500 Records and Table 2 has Millions of Records.
- Table 2 may/may not have the 500 Records of Table 1 in it.

I have to compare Table 1 and Table 2. But the result should give me only the Records of Table 1 which has any data change in Table 2. Means the Result should be less than or equal to 500.

**I don't have any primary key** but the columns in the 2 tables are same. I have written the following query. But I am getting **time out exception** and it is taking much time to process. Please help.

```
With CTE_DUPLICATE(OLD_FIRSTNAME ,New_FirstName,      
    OLD_LASTNAME ,New_LastName,      
    OLD_MINAME ,New_MIName ,      
    OLD_FAMILYID,NEW_FAMILYID,ROWNUMBER)      
as (        
 Select distinct      

    OLD.FIRST_NAME AS 'OLD_FIRSTNAME' ,New.First_Name  AS 'NEW_FIRSTNAME',      
    OLD.LAST_NAME AS 'OLD_LASTNAME',New.Last_Name AS 'NEW_LASTNAME',      
    OLD.MI_NAME AS 'OLD_MINAME',New.MI_Name AS 'NEW_MINAME',      
    OLD.FAMILY_ID AS 'OLD_FAMILYID',NEW.FAMILY_ID AS 'NEW_FAMILYID',      
    row_number()over(partition by OLD.FIRST_NAME ,New.First_Name,      
    OLD.LAST_NAME ,New.Last_Name,      
    OLD.MI_NAME ,New.MI_Name ,      
    OLD.FAMILY_ID,NEW.FAMILY_ID       
    order by OLD.FIRST_NAME ,New.First_Name,      
    OLD.LAST_NAME ,New.Last_Name,      
    OLD.MI_NAME ,New.MI_Name ,      
    OLD.FAMILY_ID,NEW.FAMILY_ID )as rank       
 From EEMSCDBStatic OLD,EEMS_VIPFILE New where            
 OLD.MPID <> New.MPID    and old.FIRST_NAME <> New.First_Name  
 and OLD.LAST_NAME <> New.Last_Name and OLD.MI_NAME <> New.MI_Name   
 and old.Family_Id<>New.Family_id    
 )      
 sELECT OLD_FIRSTNAME ,New_FirstName,      
    OLD_LASTNAME ,New_LastName,      
    OLD_MINAME ,New_MIName ,      
    OLD_FAMILYID,NEW_FAMILYID FROM CTE_DUPLICATE where rownumber=1
```

Comment: "I don't have any primary key" - erm, why not?

Comment: You can make with `JOIN` (if you don't have keys the `JOIN` will be slowest). But I think that comparing only one field will be faster... and with `CASE` or `IF` if the comparision fail (distinct values) proceed with the second field and then the third and then ... Worst case will be 500 rows and all the fields, but conditional.

Comment: Why do you write `Table 1` instead of `EEMSCDBStatic`? `Table 1` = `EEMSCDBStatic`  Any indexes on that tables?

Comment: What do you mean with *which has any data change*? If there is no unique key to tell which record corresponds with which record in the other table how would you know if a *Michael Smith* in both tables is the same person? And do you want to return the rows which exist in both tables or the one *which has any data change*? What exactly is a *data change* in your context?

Comment: Also you are using <> condition, which will join each row of your table 1 with millions of rows of table 2 (as there only one match possible). So you will be getting millions of rows instead of 'Result should be less than or equal to 500'

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is that your query is forcing the DB to fully multiply your tables, which means processing ~500M combinations. It happens because you're connecting any record from T1 with any record from T2 that has at least one different value, including `MPID` that looks like the unique identifier that must be used to connect records.

If `MPID` is really the column that identifies records in both tables then your query should have a bit different structure:

```
SELECT old.FIRSTNAME, new.FirstName,
       old.LASTNAME, new.LastName,
       old.MINAME, new.MIName,
       old.FAMILYID, new.FAMILYID
    FROM EEMSCDBStatic old
         INNER JOIN EEMS_VIPFILE new ON old.MPID = new.MPID
    WHERE old.FIRST_NAME <> New.First_Name  
          AND OLD.LAST_NAME <> New.Last_Name
          AND OLD.MI_NAME <> New.MI_Name   
          AND old.Family_Id <> New.Family_id
    ORDER BY old.FIRSTNAME, new.FirstName,
             old.LASTNAME, new.LastName,
             old.MINAME, new.MIName,
             old.FAMILYID, new.FAMILYID
```

A couple of other thoughts:

1. If you're looking for *any* change in a record (even if only one column has different values), you should use `OR`s in the `WHERE` clause, not `AND`s. Now you're only looking for records that changed values in *all* columns. For instance, you'll fail to find a person who changed his or her first name but decided to keep last name.
2. You should obviously consider indexing your tables if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it is pointless to use `DISTINCT` keyword together with `ROWNUMBER`.

See this  [sql query distinct with Row_Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121130/sql-query-distinct-with-row-number).

You are doing CROSS JOIN, which is terribly big in your case.

Perhaps in that condition you

```
where   OLD.MPID <> New.MPID and old.FIRST_NAME <> New.First_Name and ...
```

you wanted to have OR instead of AND?

It is also not entirely clear why you use `ROWNUMBER` at all - perhaps to find the best match.

All this is because as @Shnugo correctly remarked, the logic behind your comparing is faulty - you must have some logic defined that would JOIN the tables (Like First and second name must be the same).